# Mule: SFTP PKI File allowing Mule expression for path to file instead of string

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I have a path to a file held in a variable set within the mule flow called certificateFilePath. In the SFTP I have set the identityFile attribute as follow:
identifyFile="#['certificateFilePath']"

However, I get that #['certificateFilePath'] is not found as an error when running my flow, as if the expression had not been evaluated.

If I switch to identityFile="/my/actual/path/cert.pem", then it works.

Can't I use a Mule expression for identityFile. I can use expressions for other attributes, like user, path, password. I would expect identityFile to be able to have a dynamic value. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks,

Comment: At this point I'm trying to set the file path as a property at runtime (while the flow is running), and then using that with the ${} notation inside my identityFile attribute. Is there a way to access a message property using ${}?